# PHP Keep SSH session alive/stored

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssh, phpseclib

I'm using Codeigniter and below is the code that i use to get some info from a device through SSH. The whole process takes about 2.2 seconds to be executed with 2 seconds being the login process. Is there any way i can store or keep the session alive at least for a certain amount of time ??
The library i'm using for the connection is `phpseclib`

```
        $time = microtime(true);
        $this->ssh2->Net_SSH2('XX.XX.XX.XX');
        if (!$this->ssh2->login('XXXX', 'XXXXXXXX')) {
            exit('Login Failed');
        }
        echo (microtime(true) - $time) . ' elapsed';
        $string = $this->ssh2->exec('/usr/www/status.cgi');
```

Comment: Do you really mean what the server disconnects your session after **2 seconds of inactivity**? Or what problem are actually facing?

Comment: I want to execute some commands every 15-20 seconds without having to log in every single time to run that command. Basically it's going to be a cron job getting stats from a device every 15-20 seconds

Comment: So what is the problem? Why don't you put it in cron?

Comment: I do have it on cron but i have to login every single time i run the function. I want to avoid having to login every 15 seconds.

Comment: You can't start / stop a PHP script and have the connection stay alive. You'd have to have a persistent socket to keep the connection open and PHP's `pfsockopen` isn't really up for the task. You could just have the script run forever I guess. Have it sleep for 15 seconds after every call. At that point a keep-alive from phpseclib might be necessary (ie. sleep for 7 seconds, send the keep-alive and sleep for another 7 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make SSH log in without prompting you for password is to use public key cryptography.

Look up [SSH login automation](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html). To cite the site in case it goes down:

> Your aim
>
> You want to use Linux and OpenSSH to automate your tasks. Therefore you need an automatic login from host A / user a to Host B / user b. You don't want to enter any passwords, because you want to call ssh from a within a shell script.
>
> How to do it
>
> First log in on A as user a and generate a pair of authentication keys. Do not enter a passphrase:
>
> ```
> a@A:~> ssh-keygen -t rsa
> Generating public/private rsa key pair.
> Enter file in which to save the key (/home/a/.ssh/id_rsa): 
> Created directory '/home/a/.ssh'.
> Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
> Enter same passphrase again: 
> Your identification has been saved in /home/a/.ssh/id_rsa.
> Your public key has been saved in /home/a/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
> The key fingerprint is:
> 3e:4f:05:79:3a:9f:96:7c:3b:ad:e9:58:37:bc:37:e4 a@A
> ```
>
> Now use ssh to create a directory ~/.ssh as user b on B. (The directory may already exist, which is fine):
>
> ```
> a@A:~> ssh b@B mkdir -p .ssh
> b@B's password:
> ```
>
> Finally append a's new public key to `b@B:.ssh/authorized_keys` and enter b's password one last time:
>
> ```
> a@A:~> cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh b@B 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
> b@B's password:
> ```
>
> From now on you can log into B as b from A as a without password:
>
> ```
> a@A:~> ssh b@B
> ```

Other than that, daemonizing PHP process so that it maintains its session in the background is a bad idea:

1. PHP is bad for this.
2. The second anything happens: power outage, reboot, ..., your setup is gone. By that time you'll probably have forgotten it does such thing.